# How to run a script with a .desktop file without rising an icon in sidebar (Launcher in Unity)

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I want to run a ScreenRotator python script with double click. Unfortunately it's always opened as a text file in gedit. I don't want that. So I want to run it with a .desktop file. But I don't need a Launcher icon, it has top-menu icon. That's enough for me.

Comment: You create the `.desktop` file without an entry for `Icon` and that should be it!

Comment: Right click on the .desktop file > Properties > Allow to execute file as a program - More to read here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Comment: I am not a noob. The app can be started. Without icon there will be an "?" icon.